# Use FormDialog in sdk v4 of Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, chatbot

I have a chat bot that I built in sdk v3. I am updating the bot to sdkv4 and moving it to core2.0.

```
   protected async Task<DialogTurnResult> BeginChildDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, OnTurnProperty onTurnProperty)
    {
        var activity = dc.Context.Activity;
        var actionValue = onTurnProperty.Intent;
        switch (onTurnProperty.Intent)
        {

            case "quickquote":
                await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync("THIS IS QUICK QUOTE!");
                var survey = new FormDialog<QQForm>(new QQForm(), QQForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, null);
                dc.Call(survey, AfterSurvey);
```

When I am calling the form that I built using formdialog. I get the error at `dc.call(survey,AfterSurvey)`

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'DialogContext' does not contain a definition for 'Call'
>   and no accessible extension method 'Call' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'DialogContext' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I change my formdialog in sdk v4?

Comment: FormFlow was taken out of v4, so if you're updating, that will need to be adapted.

Comment: updated to what? can you point me out in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bot Framework v4 no longer has the concept of FormFlows. The way to archive this is using a combination of various techniques. I would recommend reading the following:

- [Dialog types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#dialog-types)
- [Parse and validate input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-primitive-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#parse-and-validate-input)
- [Implement sequential conversation
  flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#initialize-your-bot-and-define-your-dialog)

After going through this documents, you should have enough to start adapting your code.

Another fairly good example of collecting various inputs from users is provided in the official bot builder sample repo. Have a look [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt/MultiTurnPromptsBot.cs).

I would go for a `ComponentDialog` containing a `WaterfallDialog` with a few validations. This way you can reuse everything as you're used to do it with form flows.